# Error Firebase com.firebase.client.core.Context.a on Signed APK

Tags: android, firebase

I am building Submission Form on Android Application using Firebase Realtime Database. The debug version of apk is working fine but crash on signed apk. I have checked the google json that i am using the right one. Here is the log i got from crashlytics.

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2320)
       at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1725)
       at com.firebase.client.core.Context.a(Context.java:27)
       at com.firebase.client.Firebase.setAndroidContext(Firebase.java:2)
       at com.mikrosium.wallpaper.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:54)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2836)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2958)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1654)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6653)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Here is the ChatActivity. MainActivity is working fine, the crash is only occured only on this activity.

```
package com.mikrosium.wallpaper;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button SubmitButton ;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    LinearLayout ll_adView;
    EditText NameEditText;

    public static final String Firebase_Server_URL = "myfirebaseurl";

    String ContentHolder;

    Firebase firebase;

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    public static final String Database_Path = "myfirebasedatabasename";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        ll_adView = findViewById(R.id.ll_adView);
        toolbar = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_setting);
        toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.nav_request));
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(ChatActivity.this);

        firebase = new Firebase(Firebase_Server_URL);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Database_Path);

        SubmitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);

        NameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);

        SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                RequestDetails requestDetails = new RequestDetails();

                GetDataFromEditText();

                requestDetails.setRequest_Wallpaper(ContentHolder);


                String WallpaperRequestIDFromServer = databaseReference.push().getKey();

                databaseReference.child(WallpaperRequestIDFromServer).setValue(requestDetails);

                Context c = ChatActivity.this;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(c,
                        c.getResources().getString(R.string.success_request),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });

    }
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                break;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;
    }
    public void GetDataFromEditText(){

        ContentHolder = NameEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `ProGuard` when making the release build? If so, you might need to do the following: [Configure ProGuard](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard)

Comment: I have configured it but still crash with same error.

Comment: also try disabling `minify` in your `build.gradle` like this: `buildTypes { release { minifyEnabled false ... } }`

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using? `Firebase.setAndroidContext(..)` was used in older SDKs, I don't think it's even needed anymore. But try changing `Firebase.setAndroidContext(ChatActivity.this);` to `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);`. They have simplified and changed the initialization setup a lot in the last year or 2. Double check if your libraries are up to date to the latest and configured according to this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#assistant